# copy files from one directory to another one with controls

Tags: bash

The following code...first detects if exists a folder, and if it exists, copy the files inside (if there are more than 12 or 12) to another folder.

In the first step...there is a loop...if the folder exists, the programme tries sometimes (in this case 10 times) if the folder exists.

If the folder exists, it waits for 12 files...if there are less than 12 files...the programme, after some seconds...repeat the control...if at the end there are 12 files or more...the programme copies these files in a second folder.

I would like to share the code...maybe there is a better way to do that..safer...cleaner. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAM=`date +%Y%m%d`12
dir_origen=/home/Enric/Produccio/Grib/GFS0.50/
dir_desti=/home/Enric/Produccio/Grib/GFS0.50BIS/
cd $dir_origen/

if test -e 'gfs-0.5.'$PARAM/; then
echo "Directory exists"
else
echo "Directory doesn't exist"
cont=10

until [ $cont -lt 1 ] || test -e 'gfs-0.5.'$PARAM/; do 
echo "still we don't have the folder" 
sleep 10
let cont-=1
done
fi

if test -e 'gfs-0.5.'$PARAM/; then
cd 'gfs-0.5.'$PARAM/
echo "the folder exists" 
mkdir $dir_desti'gfs.'$PARAM
cont=10
until [ $cont -lt 1 ];do
files=`ls | wc -l | cat $VAR1`
pesT=`du -sk | awk '{print $1}' | cat $VAR3`
if [ $pesT -lt 1000000  ] || [ $files -lt 12 ]; then    
PARAM4=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
echo $pesT"k < 1000000k total"
echo $files "files of 12 waiting files"
echo "incomplete"   
else     
echo $pesT"k"
echo $files "files"
cp  $dir_origen'gfs-0.5.'$PARAM/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f* $dir_desti'gfs.'$PARAM
chmod -R 777 $dir_desti'gfs.'$PARAM/*
echo "GFS-0.5 $PARAM downloaded"
let cont=1
exit
fi
let cont-=1
sleep 10
done
fi
```

Comment: You could start by quoting your parameter expansions, and run the code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ :-)

Comment: From your description, it sounds like this question might be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).